# поменять местами цифры в матрице

Tags: python, матрицы

Есть такая [задача](https://leetcode.com/problems/rotate-image/):

Код ниже:

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 3], 
          [4, 5, 6], 
          [7, 8, 9]]

matrix.reverse()
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(i):
        matrix[i][j], matrix[j][i] = matrix[j][i], matrix[i][j]

print(matrix)
```

Объясните пожалуйста почему когда я ставлю в конце перед принтом `matrix.reverse()`, то получаю другой ответ совсем(такой: `[[3, 6, 9], [2, 5, 8], [1, 4, 7]]`). В чем разница? И как работает обмен элементов, как программа понимает что именно 741 852 963 нужно ставить?
Только учусь, поэтому не судите строго. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Матрица состоит из строк и столбцов. Когда Вы используете reverse, строки меняются местами со столбцами - это называется транспонированием. Таким образом строки 1,4,7; 2,5,8; 3,6,9; превращаются в столбцы, аналогичная ситуация со столбцами, которые встают на место строк

Comment: а как программа понимает что нужно именно в таком порядке ставить когда я меняю `[i][j]`

Comment: Используя reverse происходит транспонирование с конца, т.к. сама функция ставит последние элементы на место первых, и наоборот. Используя циклы транспонирование идёт с начала, как в обычном математическом примере

Comment: понял, спасибо за ответ